# totally stuck on RegEx that works on test sandbox but doesn't work live

Tags: php, regex

I'm totally stuck on this.

I wrote this RegEx pattern which is supposed to get the value of a string from a file whose contents I am getting with file_get_contents();

The RegEx I wrote is this:

```
/.*\$test_variable\s*=\s*'?(.*?)'?;.*/is
```

My function is:

```
function tbs_quick_setting_find($variable) {
global $savedsettings;
$setting = preg_replace("/.*\$".$variable."\s*=\s*'?(.*?)'?;.*/is",'$1',$savedsettings);
if (!empty($setting)) {
    return $setting;
} else {
    return false; // value is NOT set
    }
}
```

Strangely, this works fine when tested, like here: http://regex101.com/r/wN4lJ3
but it does not work when I test it on my website, instead of the value of the variable I get the entire contents of the $savedsettings file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: what's in `$variable` (hint: don't say what you think is in it, print/echo it first and prove you're right)

Comment: Definitely var_dump() $savedsettings, $setting, and $variable right before - and right after - calling preg_replace(). Gremlins are sneaking in on you.

Comment: That regex101 test is using a match. You are using `preg_replace`, only changing part of the input. Try `preg_match`.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans $variable definitely contains the right stuff as I am calling it with tbs_quick_setting_find('test_variable');

Comment: @BrianDHall I have done a var_dump() of those three variables and they are all strings.

Comment: @mario The regex101 is using a replacement, not a match, as you can see I have the back reference set to $2 and the replacement does work. I don't think I can use preg_match if I don't know what the value of the variable is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Matching a $ sign with PHP regex - How and why to escape*

I usually put the pattern into single quotes, where a single `\` should be enough to escape a `$` as a literal. To match `$` in a double-quoted regex-pattern things can be confusing.

All those variants should work:

1.) Using **single quotes** for the pattern, **one** `\` should be enough to escape `$` as a literal

```
'/.*\$'.$variable.'\s*=\s*\'?(.*?)\'?;.*/is'
```

2.) Imho using **double quotes**, you would have to **double-escape** the `$` because inside a regex pattern it's a [metacharater](http://www.hscripts.com/tutorials/regular-expression/metacharacter-list.php) that matches position of string- or line-end, additionally it interpolates a variable inside double-quotes. Why tripple-escape it? No idea yet :-)

```
"/.*\\$".$variable."\s*=\s*'?(.*?)'?;.*/is"
```

3.) Whether you're using double or singe-quotes for the pattern, a safe way should always be to put the `$` into a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html):

```
"/.*[$]".$variable."\s*=\s*'?(.*?)'?;.*/is"
```

Please feel free to comment/correct, where I'm wrong.

Comment: Nice answer. And now I see where [this regex](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20812426/1438393) comes from :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function tbs_quick_setting_find($variable) {
  global $savedsettings;
  $re = "/.*\\\$" . $variable . "\s*=\s*'?(.*?)'?;.*/is"; 
  $setting = preg_replace($re,'$1',$savedsettings);
  if (!empty($setting)) {
      return $setting;
  } else {
      return false; // value is NOT set
  }
}
```

problem was here `\\\$`. We need to scape de the "\" and the "$" caracter for the expression work.

#### example:

```
echo "/.*\$".$variable."\s*=\s*'?(.*?)'?;.*/is";
```

will spit this expression `/.*$test_variable\s*=\s*'?(.*?)'?;.*/is` (don't match with anything)

The correct way would be:

```
echo "/.*\\\$".$variable."\s*=\s*'?(.*?)'?;.*/is";
```

which spits this expression `/.*\$test_variable\s*=\s*'?(.*?)'?;.*/is` (which match correctly)

Comment: thank you that totally worked but I am not quite sure why... the only difference is that you escaped the single quotes, which I had not escaped because I wanted to match them literally. I had defined my pattern between double quotes so that I wouldn't need to escape the single quotes again. What am I missing?

Comment: you just edited your answer to something different... your original post (which is what my first comment was related to) contained this: `code`$re = '/.*\$' . $variable . '\s*=\s*\'?(.*?)\'?;.*/is'; `code` and it DID work... then you changed it to something different that also works, but I am not sure why you escaped the \ since I am using that to escape the $ sign of the variable beginning

Comment: Hmm no. The problem is in your $ caracter. For the expression works fine, we need to output this `.*\$test_variable\s*=\s*'?(.*?)'?;.*` (see the `\$`). What you were spitting was `.*$test_variable\s*=\s*'?(.*?)'?;.*` (note: the `$` is single.) so it was matching with nothing. (don't know if I am being clear)