# RegEx to match value of a variable or a string (with or without quotes)

Tags: php, regex, string, variables

Here is my dilemma:

I wrote this RegEx pattern which works in my sandbox but does not work on my website:

Sandbox: http://regex101.com/r/vP3uG4

Pattern:

```
(.*[$]'.$variable.'\s*=\s*\'?)(.*?)(\'?;.*)
```

The line of code goes like this:

```
$savedsettings_new = preg_replace('/(.*[$]'.$variable.'\s*=\s*\'?)(.*?)(\'?;.*)/is','$1'. $value .'$3',$savedsettings_temp);
```

As you can see it works on the sandbox but it doesn't work live.

I am trying to match values of variables that can be expressed as strings (with single quotes around them) or numerical values with no quotes, like so:

```
$match_string = 'value';
$match_number = 1;
```

Right now this code works fine with strings but with numerical variables that are not enclosed in strings I just get the contents of the backreference $3 and I don't get anything at all before that!

I'm scratching my head and really can't figure out why it works on RegEx101 but not live... Aren't I doing the right thing when matching for one or no single quotes (and escaping them because the preg_replace has quotes?

Comment: Can you show us the full PHP code? What does `$variable`, `$value`, etc contain? what is the expected output?

Comment: @AmalMurali  $variable is the name of the variable (without the $ sign) and $value is the new value i want to assign to that variable. If you look at the regex101.com link I posted you'll see an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, found out the issue. The solution is to wrap the backreference in `${}`.

Quoting the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

> When working with a replacement pattern where a backreference is immediately followed by another number (i.e.: placing a literal number immediately after a matched pattern), you cannot use the familiar `\\1` notation for your backreference. `\\11`, for example, would confuse preg_replace() since it does not know whether you want the `\\1` backreference followed by a literal `1`, or the `\\11` backreference followed by nothing. In this case **the solution is to use `\${1}1`**.

So, your code should look like:

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

$variable = 'tbs_development';
$value = '333';

$savedsettings_temp = <<<'CODE'
$tbs_underconstruction = 'foo';
$tbs_development = 0;
CODE;

$pattern = '/(.*[$]'.preg_quote($variable).'\s*=\s*\'?)(.*?)(\'?;.*)/is';
$replacement = '${1}'.$value.'${3}';

$savedsettings_new = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $savedsettings_temp);

echo $savedsettings_new;
```

Output:

```
$tbs_underconstruction = 'foo';
$tbs_development = 333;
```

[**Demo.**](https://eval.in/83679)

Comment: Yea, e.g. if `$value = 333;` then `'$1'. $value .'$3'` would be the same as `$1333$3` which does not work. Nice whoever wrote it first.

Comment: @Jonny5: I posted it about 1 hour before revo. You can see that in the [question's timeline](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20812426/timeline) (not that it's a big deal anyway :). Took me some time to figure it out though ^_^

Comment: I see! Nice to figure that out @Amal Murali

Comment: @AmalMurali thank you so much for your help! I would have never found that out! THANK YOU!!!

Answer (score 1):

If the variable `$value` contains a numerical value then the replacement pattern in your `preg_replace` will look like this: `$12$3`

That's true but not as you expected. In Regex Engine, `$ddd` or here `$dd` (which are equal to `\ddd` and `\dd`) are treated as octal numbers.

So in this case `$12` means a octal index 12 which is equal to a kind of space in ASCII.

In the case of working with these tricky issues in Regular Expressions you should wrap your backreference number within `{}` so it should be `${1}2${3}`

Change your replacement pattern to `'${1}'.$value.'${3}'`