# while coverting perl regular expression to php Not able to get php equivalent code

Tags: php, perl

I have given a task to convert Perl code to PHP code .

While doing conversion i got a regular expression which is in Perl syntax & working of the regular expression is like we are passing dynamic count to expression and after that dynamic count it add a  tag into a string .i want to the same thing in PHP but I am not able to convert it using preg_replace in PHP

Perl Code:

```
    $msg = 'Testing a string testing it again Testing';
    $count =7;
    $msg =~ s/([A-Za-z0-9\_\-\=\.]{$count})/$1<wbr>\n/ig;

    print $msg;

    Its Output is 

    Testing<wbr>                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    a string testing<wbr>                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    it again Testing<wbr>
```

can anyone help me to get this done ?It would be the great help .

Comment: on which part are you stuck ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx to match value of a variable or a string (with or without quotes)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20812426/regex-to-match-value-of-a-variable-or-a-string-with-or-without-quotes)

Answer (score 3):

This is probably what you are looking for.

```
$msg = preg_replace('/([A-Za-z0-9\_\-\=\.]{' . $count . '})/i', '\1<wbr>' . "\n", $msg);
```

You can test PHP regular expressions at [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/kB0dX4/1) easily (see this expression under the link).

Comment: @user3381968 Would you please be so kind to accept the answer, not just upvote? Thanks!