# Replace unicode formatted special characters

Tags: php, regex, unicode

I need to replace special characters inside a string with other characters. For example a "ä" can be replaced by either "a" or "ae" and a "à" with "a" as well. Normally this is pretty easy to do with PHP and there are lots of functions on stackoverflow, which already do excactly that.

Unfortunately my string looks like this: "u\u0308 a\u0302 a\u0308 o\u0300.zip" (ü â ä ò.zip). As you might see my strings are file names and OSX seems to convert the characters to unicode (at least that is what i think).

I know that i could use a very long array with all special characters to replace them in PHP:

```
$str = "u\u0308 a\u0302 a\u0308 o\u0300.zip";

$ch = array("u\u0308", "a\u0302", "a\u0308", "o\u0300");
$chReplace = = array("u", "a", "a", "o");

str_replace($ch, $chReplace, $str);
```

But I'm wondering if there is an easier way, so I don't have to do this manually for every character?

Comment: [mb_convert_encoding()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) or [iconv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) with `//TRANSLIT`

Comment: `utf8_encode($data)` might also work.

Comment: @PimVerlangen `utf8_encode` outputs the same string, so "u\u0308 a\u0302 a\u0308 o\u0300.zip"

Comment: @MarkBaker What do i have to use as charset/encoding type?

Comment: If you're trying to convert UTF-8 to whatever charset is used by your filesystems, then those are the charsets that you specify for mb_convert_encoding() or iconv()

Comment: @MarkBaker I'm trying to convert the string above (which looks like unicode to me?) to "normal" characters, so in my case "ü â ä ò". So I think I'm looking for `mb_convert_encoding($str, WHAT_ENCODING_HERE, "UTF-8");`

Comment: What charset is it likely to be? I can only guess! "ISO-8859-1" perhaps

Comment: @MarkBaker Thanks, need to figure that out, i don't know much about charsets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve this problem by dividing it into multiple steps:

- Convert the Unicode code points to actual entities. This can be easily achieved using [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/preg_replace). For an explanation of how the regex works, see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20931193/1438393).
- Now you will have a set of characters like `u&#x0308;`. These are HTML entities. To convert them into their corresponding character forms, use [`html_entity_decode()`](http://php.net/html_entity_decode).
- You will now have a UTF-8 string. You need to convert it into ISO-8859-1 (Official ISO 8-bit Latin-1). The `//TRANSLIT` part is to enable transileration. If this is enabled, when a character can't be represented in the target charset, it will try to approximate the result.

Code:

```
// Set the locale to something that's UTF-8 capable
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8');

$str = "u\u0308 a\u0302 a\u0308 o\u0300";

// Convert the codepoints to entities
$str = preg_replace("/\\\\u([0-9a-fA-F]{4})/", "&#x\\1;", $str);

// Convert the entities to a UTF-8 string
$str = html_entity_decode($str, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

// Convert the UTF-8 string to an ISO-8859-1 string
echo iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT", $str);
```

Output:

```
u a a o
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/TlsAwv)

Comment: Thanks a lot, haven't thought of entities! Not sure what part of the code is causing this, but if there is no space in between the unicode characters the code will output "?". So "a\u0308a\u0308" (ää) outputs "a?". I tried adding a {4} to the regex "'/\\\\u([0-9a-f]+){4}/i'", but it doesn't seem to fix the problem.

Comment: @demrks: What should it output instead? `aa`?

Comment: Yes, in this case 'aa'. If the string is "o\u0308u\u0308" (öü) something like "ou".

Comment: Strange, "öü" actually works, but "ää" (-> "aa") doesn't, see https://eval.in/129478

Comment: Got it, this regex works for me: `preg_replace("/\\\\u([0-9a-fA-F]{4})/", "&#x\\1;", $string)`

Comment: @demrks: Excellent. Thanks for taking the time to investigate the issue. I've now updated my answer to include the working solution. Cheers!