# Find the occurrence of backslash in a string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

If my string is : `aud\ios`, how do i check it out for the presence of `\` in it?

I tried using `preg_match('\\' , $string)` but it does not work. What's the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: Look into [`strpos()`](http://br1.php.net/strpos)

Comment: strpos is enough for such an easy match.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For something simple as this, you don't need a regular expression. A string function like [`strpos()`](http://php.net/strpos) should be enough:

```
if (strpos('aud\ios', '\\') !== FALSE) {
    // String contains '\'
}
```

Note that you need to escape the backslash here. If you simply write `\`, then PHP considers it as an escape sequence and tries to escape the character that follows. To avoid this, you need to escape the escape using another backslash: `\\`.

As for matching a literal backslash using a `preg_*` function, you'll need to use `\\\\` instead of a single `\`.

From the [PHP manual documentation on *Escape Sequences*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php):

> Single and double quoted PHP strings have special meaning of backslash. Thus if `\` has to be matched with a regular expression `\\`, then `"\\\\"` or `'\\\\'` must be used in PHP code.

So your code would look like:

```
preg_match('/\\\\/', $string); // Don't use this though
```

where:

- `/` - starting delimiter
- `\\\\` - matches a single literal `\`
- `/` - ending delimiter

For additional information about this, see:

- [How to properly escape a backslash to match a literal backslash in single-quoted and double-quoted PHP regex patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20818283/how-to-properly-escape-a-backslash-to-match-a-literal-backslash-in-single-quoted)

Comment: Thanks for the info ! :) 
I simplty used : 

strpos($newfoldername, '\\') 

Had to use double \\

Answer (score 0):

```
if (strstr('aud\ios', '\\') !== false) {
    //Contains "\"
}
```

Comment: From the manual: "*If you only want to determine if a particular needle occurs within haystack, use the faster and less memory intensive function **strpos()** instead.*"

Comment: Doesn't make any actual difference here, but yeah, I suppose strpos would be more correct.

Answer (score 0):

I use this function a lot, you can easily check if a `string` `contains`

```
function StringContains($the_string,$contains)
{
    return strpos($the_string, $contains) !== FALSE;
}
```

check it out: http://3v4l.org/LrDBd

of course you have to escape the backslash when calling the function like this
`StringContains('aud\ios','\\');`

Comment: Might as well do just: `return strpos($the_string, $contains) !== FALSE;`.