# Regular Expression working in online test tool, but not in my app

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I've got the following snippet:

```
$file = '/mnt/stoneshare/cache/video/10_12_101_38/000/011/M00001.mp4';

preg_match('/[\/\\](\d+_\d+_\d+_\d+)[\/\\]/', $file, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

Which, apparently, produces:

> `preg_match(): Compilation failed: missing terminating ] for character class at offset 27`

Yet, when I run the same example in an online test tool, [it works](http://regex101.com/r/cV4rW7).

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add an escape:

```
preg_match('/[\/\\\](\d+_\d+_\d+_\d+)[\/\\\]/', $file, $matches);
//       here __^       and           __^
```

Comment: Yes, works! But, why so? It looks incorrect - as if I'd escape backslash and then also escape bracket, and my IDE screws up syntax highlighting this way. And yes, the online tool errors out on this one.

Comment: @jolt: I don't know the real reason of this behaviour. It's different in other language as perl for example where `[\/\\\]` is an erreur.

Comment: @jolt `var_dump($pattern);` your original regex: `/[\/\]...` the regex parser needs a properly escaped backslash. Also see my [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20818283/how-to-properly-escape-a-backslash-to-match-a-literal-backslash-in-single-quoted), if you need more input :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add one more backslash in your pattern.

```
preg_match('/[\/\\\](\d+_\d+_\d+_\d+)[\/\\\]/', $file, $matches);
```

Because the backslash is itself a special character, you need to escape it with another backslash ( \ ) if
you want to include it literally in an expression. What ’ s more, because a backslash followed by another
character within a string is itself seen as an escaped character in PHP, you usually need to add a third
backslash ( \\ ). Phew!

Answer (score 0):

I would try this:

```
preg_match('/^\/.*(\d+_\d+_\d+_\d+)\/.*$/', $file, $matches);
```

Comment: THis doesn't match the same things that OP wants.

Comment: How so? It looks to me like he wants the (\d+_\d+_\d+_\d+) part?

Comment: He want the delimiters to be slash `/` or backslash `\` also the numbers are between delimiters (not preceded by any char). And why do you put `.*$` at the end?

Comment: Ah, OK - then maybe preg_match('/^\/.*\/(\d+_\d+_\d+_\d+)\//', $file, $matches); would do the trick (just added in an extra delimiter before the digits start. I suppose .*$ is not actually needed then, good point.