# Remove a div by id with preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace

hello i have an html string with output

```
$incoming_data = '<div id=\"title\">a title</div>';
```

And i want to remove it with preg_replace

i tried the code bellow without any luck..

```
result = preg_replace('#<div id="title">(.*?)</div>#', ' ', $incoming_data);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Any ideas? Yep, show the actual HTML source (without escaped quotes for example). And when unversed with regex, use a DOM traversal frontend for modifying HTML. (Except if it's really for repetitive templating tasks of course.)

Comment: Also, be sure you are doing `$result =`, with the `$`.

Comment: Any help how to do this with DOM travesal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `$incoming_data` contains escaped quotes, so you have to [escape the backslash for the php regex pattern to match it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20818283/how-to-properly-escape-a-backslash-to-match-a-literal-backslash-in-single-quoted).

Then your updated code would be:

```
$incoming_data = '<div id=\"title\">a title</div>';
$result = preg_replace('#<div id=\\\"title\\\">(.*?)</div>#', ' ', $incoming_data);
```

If you first want to strip the slashes from the string, you can use the [stripslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) function.

Then your updated code would be:

```
$incoming_data = stripslashes('<div id=\"title\">a title</div>');
$result = preg_replace('#<div id="title">(.*?)</div>#', ' ', $incoming_data);
```

For the dom traversal you can use the [DOMDocument class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).