# PHP preg_match function not working as expected

Tags: php, regex

I want to find the index of the pattern from the string and find all Unicode characters like "\u2026","\u2021","\u2011" and so on.

Below is the code snippet I am currently using. But it is resulting in else situation.

```
if(preg_match('/[\\^]u[0-9]{4}/gi',$data['title'],$matches,PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)){
     print_r($matches);
}
else{
     echo "Not Found";
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Which output do you expect?

Comment: Show the text input. Note that `g` flag is not supported, you need to use `preg
_match_all`

Comment: Thank you, @WiktorStribiżew for suggesting preg_match_all, using that and modified pattern it works!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues with your code.

1. If you're using single quotes for the pattern and want to [match a literal backslash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20819109/5527985), you need to use at least `\\\` or even `\\\\` to produce an escaped backslash `\\`. Just echo your pattern if unsure.
2. Instead of using the *global flag* `g` which is not available in PHP use [`preg_match_all`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php). If it matches, it returns the number of matches. You can check match condition by `preg_match_all(`...`) > 0`
3. Unsure about `^` in `[\\^]`. if you don't need it, drop it. Further `[0-9]` can be reduced to `\d`. Also I would add a [word boundary `\b`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) after `\d{4}` if something like `\u12345` should not be matched.

[See this PHP demo at tio.run](https://tio.run/##XY5NC4JAFEX38yseEqggZBIV2AcRWquSspUTw6hjCuYMNq7E326T0aI2j3e558IRuej75SY4BAiNUipppMtClky/wQo0GieAG8d2ZpBx/nmnw3VUmNjzheaqnaBSsrpSC32MMW5w2k47HI8L3UUsyTl8CQUXmSFqdicPKpOc0LI0/jcW/IqoPMDsaUFw9vbk5PsXLyS7bRBez54Ja7DNFgGIuqgkqY0vHtk300UdsPLJ3v2goh25BJ83VarUO9T3Lw)

```
$pattern = '/\\\u\d{4}\b/i';
# echo $pattern;

if(preg_match_all($pattern, $data['title'], $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE) > 0){
  print_r($matches[0]);
} else{
  echo "Not Found";
}
```